# android:layout_height 0dp cutting text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

This is how my blueprint looks, everything is nice and clean.
[image]

Then this is how it ends up looking in preview mode:

[image]

I have tried to fix it in many ways but is still cutting text or cells are not aligned properly. This is how the code looks at the moment.

**The Parent**

```
    <style name="matchVerticalLayout">
            <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
            <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
            <item name="android:weightSum">4</item>
```

**The Children**

```
<style name="answers">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>

 <style name="radioButtons">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/radioButton</item>
```

**The Code**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer1"
        style="@style/radioButtons"
        android:tag="A"
        android:text="@string/answer1T" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer2"
        style="@style/radioButtons"
        android:tag="B"
        android:text="@string/answer2T" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer3"
        style="@style/radioButtons"
        android:tag="C"
        android:text="@string/answer3T" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer4"
        style="@style/radioButtons"
        android:tag="D"
        android:text="@string/answer4T" />
</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout style="@style/matchVerticalLayout">

    <TextView
        style="@style/answers"
        android:text="@string/answer1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/answers"
        android:text="@string/answer2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/answers"
        android:text="@string/answer3" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/answers"
        android:text="@string/answer4" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your holder view must have some defined height, remove that and update to wrap or some relative height. Or share your view xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="answers">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check with by giving height 200dp

Comment: I can't do that because my text is different length and sometimes its 1 line text and sometimes 10 lines text.

Comment: then plz go with my posted style values